# Adding faces to an existing mesh with RhinoPython

Tags: python, rhino3d

I am using RhinoPython along with RhinoCommon to attempt to add a face to an existing mesh.  Everything seems to work, but the face that is created is not in the same location as the points that I picked.  Could someone explain why the index numbers from the picked points don't seem to be the right ones?

```
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs
import Rhino
import scriptcontext
import rhinoscript.utility as rhutil

def AddVertices(me):
    """Add face to a mesh"""
    mesh=rhutil.coercemesh(me)

    #select the vertices
    go=Rhino.Input.Custom.GetObject()
    go.GeometryFilter=Rhino.DocObjects.ObjectType.MeshVertex
    go.SetCommandPrompt("Get mesh vertex")
    go.GetMultiple(3,4)
    objrefs = go.Objects()
    point=[item.GeometryComponentIndex.Index for item in objrefs]
    go.Dispose()

    if len(point)==4:
        mesh.Faces.AddFace(point[0], point[1], point[2], point[3])
    else:
        mesh.Faces.AddFace(point[0], point[1], point[2])
    #replace mesh delete point
    scriptcontext.doc.Objects.Replace(me,mesh)
    mesh.Dispose()
    scriptcontext.doc.Views.Redraw()

if( __name__ == "__main__" ):
    me=rs.GetObject("Select a mesh to add face")
    AddVertices(me)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because what returned from the "get" operation is a MeshTopologyVertex and not a MeshVertex.  A MeshTopologyVertex represents one or more mesh vertices that happen to share the same location in space.  This is because there is a vertex normal associated with every vertex.  Think of a corner in a mesh box.  That corner has three faces with different vertex normals, hence there are three mesh vertices at that corner but only one MeshTopologyVertex.  I've adjusted the script to use a vertex index instead.

```
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs
import Rhino
import scriptcontext
import rhinoscript.utility as rhutil

def AddVertices(me):
    """Add face to a mesh"""
    mesh=rhutil.coercemesh(me)

    #select the vertices
    go=Rhino.Input.Custom.GetObject()
    go.GeometryFilter=Rhino.DocObjects.ObjectType.MeshVertex
    go.SetCommandPrompt("Get mesh vertex")
    go.GetMultiple(3,4)
    objrefs = go.Objects()
    topology_indices=[item.GeometryComponentIndex.Index for item in objrefs]
    go.Dispose()

    point = []
    for index in topology_indices:
        # in many cases there are multiple vertices in the mesh
        # for a single topology vertex. Just pick the first one
        # in this sample, you will probably have to make a better
        # decision that this for your specific case
        vertex_indices = mesh.TopologyVertices.MeshVertexIndices(index)
        point.append(vertex_indices[0])

    if len(point)==4:
        mesh.Faces.AddFace(point[0], point[1], point[2], point[3])
    else:
        mesh.Faces.AddFace(point[0], point[1], point[2])
    #replace mesh delete point
    scriptcontext.doc.Objects.Replace(me,mesh)
    mesh.Dispose()
    scriptcontext.doc.Views.Redraw()

if( __name__ == "__main__" ):
    me=rs.GetObject("Select a mesh to add face")
    AddVertices(me)
```

Comment: any methods remove this manual selection of the mesh? me=rs.GetObject("Select a mesh to add face")